# Is there a library which can generate animated SVG diagrams like this example?

Tags: python, dataflow-diagram, flow-diagram

I'm constantly doing some flow diagrams using rather "primitive" tools like draw.io / lucidchart / etc. I accidentally landed on https://thingsboard.io/docs/iot-gateway/what-is-iot-gateway/ while researching a completely different topic and immediately noticed the animated SVG diagram.

I'm wondering if there is an existing library which can generate animated SVGs based on mermaid markdown perhaps? The link contains `python` so maybe there's a python library for this?

[image: Animated SVG Flow diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also curious so [I consulted their `thingsboard/thingsboard` issues](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/6510#issuecomment-1483429038).

Then I found [an issue on `thingsboard/thingsboard-gateway`](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard-gateway/issues/980).

The tool is [Figma](https://www.figma.com/), though I know nothing about using Figma to create animated SVGs.

Comment: https://github.com/otti/EnergyFlowAnimation